# Send all the columns(<td>) for each row whose dropdown is selected from JSP to Servlet

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, jsp, servlets

I have a table in JSP page which is wrapped inside the form tag. 
Now the table has 3 columns and each row has a dropdown to select from.

My problem is that when I change the **dropdown select value and click on the button** in the form (below table), **all the data for that row**(all the td values) must be transferred to a **Servlet**.

So lets say if I change the drop down value to Available and click button, then all 3 column values:  Java(1st column), Available(2nd column) and john(3rd column) should be transferred to Servlet.
How can I possibly do that?

Here is my table:

```
<form method="post"
            action="${pageContext.request.contextPath}/DemoServlet"
            class="container">
            <div class="panel panel-default ">
                <!-- Default panel contents -->
                <div class="panel-heading">Operations form</div>
                <table class="table table-bordered">
                    <thead>
                        <tr>
                            <th class="text-center">Title</th>
                            <th class="text-center">Status</th>
                            <th class="text-center">User</th>
                        </tr>
                    </thead>
                    <tbody>
                        <c:forEach items="${entries}" var="entry">
                            <tr>
                                <td>${entry.title}</td>
                                <td class="text-center"><c:choose>
                                        <c:when test="${entry.status == 'Reserved'}">
                                            <select name="status" id="status">
                                                <option value="${entry.status }">${entry.status }</option>
                                                <option value="Available">Available</option>
                                                <option value="Checkedout">Checkedout</option>
                                            </select>
                                        </c:when>
                                        <c:when test="${entry.status == 'Checkedout'}">
                                            <select name="status" id="status">
                                                <option value="${entry.status }">${entry.status }</option>
                                                <option value="Available">Available</option>
                                            </select>
                                        </c:when>
                                        <c:otherwise>
                                            ${entry.status}
                                        </c:otherwise>
                                    </c:choose></td>
                                <td class="text-center">${entry.username}</td>
                            </tr>
                        </c:forEach>
                    </tbody>
                </table>
            </div>
            <div class="row clearfix">
                <div class="col-xs-2">
                    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Update</button>
                </div>
            </div>
        </form>
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: you need to use ajax for that.so that you can send only particular row values to servr.

Answer (score 0):

Put some sort of identifier as a data attribute on each row

```
<tr data-id="${entry.id}">
```

Then you can use a change handler on the `select` elements to make an ajax call. Using jQuery it would look something like:

```
$('select[name=status]').change(function(){
    var data={
       id   : $(this).closest('tr').data('id'),
       name : $(this).val()
    };
    $.post('path/to/server', data, function(response){
        /* validate server response and then do something in UI */
    });    
});
```

Note that element ID's must be unique by defintiion but you are repeating the same ID's in your loop to create row elements.

Reference :  [**$.post() API Docs**](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.post/)

Comment: Does this cause redirect on select change!? I need a redirect on button click.

Comment: no but you can do a simple redirect in the success callback